# Django TimeField format

Tags: python, django, time, format, models

I have time in format something like there: "10 a.m., noon". I want to have in format: 10:00, 12:00, 15:00 etc.
I've tried in my html file:

```
{{ value|time:"H:M" }}
```

I also tried in my settings

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%H:%M',)
```

Nothing work.

In my models I have:

```
time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
times= Hours_classes.objects.all()
context = {'teacher_id': teacher_id,
           'query_results': query_results,
           'times': times}
return render(request, 'planner/teacher.html', context)
```

**teacher.html**

```
<tr>
<th></th>
{% for item in times %}
    <th>{{ item.time_start|time:"H:M" }} - {{ item.time_end|time:"H:M" }} </th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

**models.py**

```
class Hours_classes(models.Model):
    time_start = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_end = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: And how are `time_start` and `time_end` defined in your model?

Comment: Without this: |time:"H:M" it display time in this strange format. With this it doesn't display at all. I added my models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"H:M"` is not a valid format to pass to the [Django template time filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#time). You need to use:

```
{{ value|time:"H:i" }}
```