# django models timefield o min:sec format

Tags: django, django-models, timefield

How can I set TimeField format in django models to be [min:sec] like for an audio track?

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    duration = models.TimeField(null=True)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store the duration in seconds as integer. Then format it to whatever you need (for example witha a template tag) when you render it?

Comment: Surly it would, it's just an exercise on the course I'm taking and I'm supposed to use TimeField in this one.

Comment: Which sounds weird, take for instance audio books which can take longer than 24h. A model btw doesn't format, that something you do in the view layer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841008/django-timefield-format

Comment: ok, now I know. What I needed was:    models.DurationField

Answer (score 0):

Create form.py in app and inherit this form in view also if you want to use same concept in admin then also inherit in django admin

```
from django import forms
from .models import Song
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    duration = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
    class Meta:
        model = Song
```